# Rollback doesn't work with Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am practicing with redshift, I have created a table:

1. Inserted values from another table
2. Delete the data from table

I have tried rollback both of this steps, but it doesn't work. What is wrong with this, I don't understand?

Comment: Redshift is fully ACID complaint, so you start transaction and rollback, it must work, provide more detailed steps, like where you are `beginning the transaction` and `committing` or `rolling it back`.

Comment: @redboy  these are all the comments            create table karthik (eventid int,venueid smallint,eventname varchar(200));
Insert into karthik (select eventid ,venueid ,eventname from event);
delete from karthik;
rollback;                  after delete i have tried roll back, after that it didn't return any values.

Comment: First step, say begin, then do everything you mentioned, it should rollback everything except table creation, as it's 'ddl'.

Comment: @redboy i have tried to execute with begin even though same  problem occured, could you send me the exact set of codes

Comment: Could you share the commands you tried? Also are you using interleaved sorting? Last time I had issues with interleaved keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **two** `psql` terminals connected to same Redshift intance and database, say `terminal-1` and `terminal-2`.

Execute following queries on `terminal-1`.

```
create table sales(
salesid integer not null Identity,
commission decimal(8,2),
saledate date,
description varchar(255),
created_at timestamp default sysdate,
updated_at timestamp);

begin;
insert into sales(commission,saledate,description,created_at,updated_at) values('3.55','2018-12-10','Test description','2018-05-17 23:54:51','2018-05-17 23:54:51');
insert into sales(commission,saledate,description,created_at,updated_at) values('5.67','2018-11-10','Test description1','2018-05-17 23:54:51','2018-05-17 23:54:51');
```

**Hold on here and go to terminal-2; don't close the terminal-1, and execute following query**

```
select * from sales;
```

You will not get above two data `records` inserted from terminal-1.

**Hold on here, again go to terminal-1; and execute below query.**

```
commit;
```

**Hold on here and go to terminal-2; execute following query again**

```
select * from sales;
```

Now, you will both records.
Point proven.

Comment: Thank you  for your time @redboy,  If i have any doubt in my future posts may i tag you??

Comment: Good to know, if could you accept it as correct answer, if it worked for you?

Comment: To be honest no, i have tried the same it didn't workout. if i execute insert command separately data would be  inserted but i cannot rollback, if i execute both begin and insert commands at the same time result says 1000 rows are affected but the data was not inserted.

Comment: Anyways, it's not possible, few pointer, make sure you don't have autocommit. Also, you are opening two terminals. Also, you could try same with your favourite language java, Python etc and other terminal.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with my end, once again thanks for your time.